# Android: Do all devices (above api 19 (Kit-Kat)) have Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, frameworks, storage

Is it reliable to use Storage Access Framework to open files from external storage, do all devices have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is "are there any API Level 19+ devices that lack the Storage Access Framework", and we cannot prove a negative.

Since support for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` is provided by the core OS, a device manufacturer would have to specifically rip those out or otherwise break their functionality. I would not expect such a device to pass the Compatibility Test Suite (though I have been wrong before on this). If you ship your app via the Play Store, you should be safe.

If you ship your app outside of the Play Store, there is an increased chance that device manufacturers will indeed have screwed this up. I do not think that it is very likely, but it is possible.

Since these are `Intent` actions, you can always use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()` to see if there is something on the device that can handle the `Intent`, and if does not exist, fall back to your pre-19 alternative.